# How to read the .mfc file which is created by HTK in python environment

Tags: python-3.x, htk

I have some file which are created by HTK file, ended by .mfc. I want to read the file into python3, Is there any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[This repo](https://github.com/danijel3/PyHTK) does it nicely:

```
from HTK import HTKFile
import numpy as np

htk_reader = HTKFile()
htk_reader.load(PATH_TO_YOUR_MFC_FILE)
result = np.array(htk_reader.data)
```

hope it helps.